# Xamarin android app crashes once its uploaded to google play store

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I recently developed an android app in Visual Studio with Xamarin and I'm able to open the app when downloading the release apk to my phone, but once I uploaded it to the google play store and try to download it and then open it crashes. And the crash log displays this error below:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)

    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at md5d38b484f2053706449e9bb7e84aa7c74.HomeFragment.n_onCreateView (Native Method)
    at md5d38b484f2053706449e9bb7e84aa7c74.HomeFragment.onCreateView (HomeFragment.java:38)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2352)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:995)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1171)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:815)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1582)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:483)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get a more verbose crash log?

The OnCreateView that the log is referencing is trying to get access to a PCL that has functions for hitting a remote api to get data from. Could this be the issue? The PCL is referenced via dll in the android app's project but is there something else I needed to do?

**UPDATE**

I'm seeing tons of responses related to this stating that is a bug with Xamarin but I'm not understanding exactly code-wise what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: Does this issue happens on android version 7.0+ device? Did you check [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56653#c21) in bugzilla?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT yes this a 7.0+ device. I did see that but I don't quite understand what I need to do to resolve whatever is causing this exception.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: For me I saw the same issue, but it had something to do with wonky Google APIs. I think when you upgrade the Android Target framework/API, some of the older functions start becoming unstable and crashing. (The PackageManager functions for me) 
So a bit of try-catch will fix it